# Can this boolean expression be simplified?

Tags: language-agnostic, boolean-logic

```
(A Or B) And Not (A And B)
```

Comment: Not beginner just went-to-bed-at-430am.

Comment: 60 views in 8 minutes? Looks like there was a rush to grab the easy rep.

Comment: The 'beginner' tag that someone edited in your question qualifies your question, not you. You don't have to take it personally, but this question is a beginner question regardless of what time you went to bed.

Comment: I didn't think of it like that.

Comment: deserves a "beginner" tag or risks being closed by the "this-is-not-maths-overflow" crowd :P

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're looking for a [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or), depending on the language it may be a single operation.

Comment: In your notation, that'd be: A Xor B

Comment: Should be optimized into a single operation by the compiler / interpreter, I would hope!

Comment: Hehe, happens to us all mate.

Answer (score 12):

It is XOR (See table below).

```
A B (A|B) (A&B) !(A&B) (A|B)&(!(A&B))
T T   T     T      F        F
T F   T     F      T        T
F T   T     F      T        T
F F   F     F      T        F
```

You can also use not equal operation like `(A != B)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree, nice trick but I think it hides the intent of the expression.

Comment: != is the right answer to this question. Simple and to the point.

Comment: Not if there is a native XOR expression.

Comment: I agree, it's only valid if there isn't a XOR operator.

Answer (score 4):

isn't this just an exclusive or?  sometimes indicated by this syntax: A ^ B

Comment: I've never in my life seen that syntax. If you showed that to any logician they would say that that meant "A and B": XOR is usually written as a "+" inside an "O" or as a "=" with a "\" through it.

Comment: That is the C based syntax which is indecently what I needed.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy  Obviously your not a c programmer...it's the bitwise xor operator.....blame k & R!!

Answer (score 3):

If you have Xor or equality in your atomic operations, yes, it is exactly the former or the negation of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this is an XOR. Note that the best ways to solve this are either a logic table as NawaMan used, or with a [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map). In EE, Karnaugh maps are more common since they lend themselves more readily to complex expressions with multiple inputs.

If you're implementing this in hardware, Karnaugh maps are nearly always the best way to go as they give you the minimum number of gates required to implement the required outputs. Also, unlike in software, you may not have an xor gate available in hardware, but each gate can be expressed as a combination of other gates. AND can be made from NAND, etc, which will increase the number of gates required but can reduce the cost of your device.