# C# - Proceed with foreach() loop if an error occurs

Tags: c#, xml, error-handling, foreach

I currently have a listview and a folder full of XML documents.  I am using a foreach() loop to go through all the XML files and load data into the listview accordingly.  My question is, how do I carry on with the foreach() loop if there is an error within in (example: if one of the XML files is not completely valid, contains errors, etc) and still add the data to the listview?  I'm not asking how to parse the XML or how to load it into the listview, that much I know how to do, just not how to proceed with the loop if an error occurs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you want:

```
foreach(var xml in xmls)
{
   try
   {
     //import xml to listview
   }
   catch (SomeException e)
   {
     //deal with the exception here
   }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 1 second ;-)

Comment: Ok, I feel like an idiot.  I had the foreach() loop within a try/catch but never even thought of doing the reverse, now I feel retarded lol. Thanks.

Comment: @Nate - See my question to feel good about yourself :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723741/can-this-boolean-expression-be-simplified

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the inner contents of the loop in a `try ... catch` block.

e.g.

```
foreach (var foo in iterableThing) {
    try {
        DoStuff(foo);
    }
    catch (AppropriateException) {
        // Handle the exception (or ignore it)...
    }
    catch (SomeOtherException) {
        // Handle the exception (or ignore it)...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wouldnt you do

```
foreach( loop )
{
   try {
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      // all errors caught here, but the loop would continue
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the file processing in a try catch block and handle the error condition. You can handle the errors gracefully in catch and continue with loading of data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this:

```
foreach(var doc in docs)
{
    //Make a function to evaluate the doc
    if(isValid(doc))
    {
        //Logging or something
        continue;
    }
    //Add data to listview
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your processing code throws exceptions, then use a `try/catch` block. If you're checking the results of some method with an `if` block, then use `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use this more often or if you just want to have more elegant code, you can use lambda expressions and delegates to create a new abstraction for this purpose:

```
static void SafeForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> op) {
  foreach(var el in source) {
    try { op(el); }
    catch (Exception e) { }
  }
}
```

Then you can write just:

```
xmls.SafeForEach(xml => {
     // Xml processing
  });
```

However, using exceptions in situations where an error is expected is not the best programming style. If you can write a method, say `IsValid` that returns true if the document is valid, then you could write:

```
foreach(var xml in xmls.Where(x => x.IsValid)) { 
  // Xml processing
}
```