# Are HttpHandlers reinstantiated every request?

Tags: asp.net, iis, httphandler

I've defined a custom HttpHandler,

```
 public class RequestHandler : IHttpHandler
```

Which I pass all my requests through,

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <add name="RequestHandler" path="*" verb="*" type="WebApplication6.RequestHandler" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```

Does this class get re-constructed every time someone requests a page or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The handler will be reused if `IHttpHandler.IsReusable` returns `true`.

[IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx)

Comment: \*forehead smack\* Doh... I knew this too. Read that when I was learning about them and then promptly forgot it as soon as it became relevant to me, apparently.

Comment: @Ralph - It happens... speaking of things I already knew: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723741/can-this-boolean-expression-be-simplified